# Making News Feed using Parse.com queries

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a news feed based on my friends and myself activities using Parse queries. I have a collection called "MeFollow" [has columns "me" "followUser"] which shows ppl I follow and another collection called "Activity" which stores `toUser, fromUser, type, content`.

this is how I find my followers:

```
 var myFollowers = new Parse.Query("MeFollow");
 myFollowers.equalTo("me", Parse.User.current());
```

but I can't find my friends activities using next query:

```
var friendsActivity = new Parse.Query("Activity");
friendsActivity.equalTo("fromUser", myFollowers.followUser);
```

my activities works fine:

```
var myActivity = new Parse.Query("Activity");
myActivity.equalTo("fromUser", Parse.User.current());
```

here is the main query:

```
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(myActivity, friendsActivity);
    mainQuery.include("fromUser");
    mainQuery.include("productId");
    mainQuery.descending("createdAt");
    mainQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    response.success(results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    // There was an error.
    }
 });
```

I think I cannot do "myFollowers.followUser"! Does anyone know how can I make this possible?

PS: I'm doing this in cloud code so it is javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use **myFollowers.followUser** because myFollowers returns objects that show relations between **me** and **followUser**, not the **followUser** objects itself.

You should use **matchesKeyInQuery** like:

```
    var friendsActivity = new Parse.Query("Activity");
    friendsActivity.matchesKeyInQuery("fromUser", "followUser",myFollowers);
```

You can check this docs which is not easily accessed in the main documentation: https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#matchesKeyInQuery

Comment: Great to hear that :)